# AnyLogic Agent-Based simulation agents value transfer

Tags: java, simulation, javaagents, agent-based-modeling, anylogic

I'm quite new with Java & AnyLogic so please get on my level for this one.

Is there a way for agents to get a variable value from another agent?
In that case, agents would be of the same type. Thus, they all have the same variables, but since it's variables with random initial values and not parameters, the values aren't the same.

Agents are also initially connected via Small-World connections and these connections are not altered during the runs.

How can agents, occurring in a Event for example, gather a variable value from another agent (e.g. Agent i gets the variable value X of agent j). This value would be put in a small equation in order to modify the value of variable X of agent i. In other words, the agent i would be affected by his connected agent j, hence altering his value of X.

I've tried multiple combinations of `.getConnectedAgent()` and `.get` without any success. I'm now trying to extract the values of X for each agent into a database and then use that database to gather the value of X of agent j by agent i, but I'm not making any progress there.

The values needed to be extracted are `double`s, but I could change the variables to integers if it would be easier.

Comment: To make Benjamin's (good) answer more explicit, if you wanted to get the value of an AnyLogic variable x from the first Agent you were connected to, then you'd use `getConnectedAgent(0).x`. (The zero in brackets tells AnyLogic *which* connected agent you want to use, where zero is the first. If you used a small-world network environment, AnyLogic has set up zero or more connections for you where the order in this case is a bit irrelevant.)

Comment: You would also need to test that there *was* actually a connection for the current Agent which there might not be so, for example, you'd put the code inside an `if (connectedNumber() > 0)` block.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to extract that into a database. You should do some more learning around object-oriented programming, your issue has less to do with AnyLogic and more with using Java properly.

If you have a population of Agents called "MyAgents", where each agent has a variable var with a random double value, then agent 12 can get the double value of agent 14 by calling `var = get_Main().MyAgents.get(13).var`.

Here, `var` on the left hand side is the var of the calling agent. `get_Main()` takes it one level up in the hierarchy to access its own population and other agents. It then accesses the 14th agent (Java is zero-based) and its var value.

If you plan to use `getConnectedAgent()`, you need to connect agents first. This is done to some extend if you use "Small world" but often, you want to define connections manually. Check the "Link to Agent" article in the help.

cheers